# Program execution stopping on atml atmega16 microcontroller upon terminal connection

Tags: python, microcontroller, virtual-serial-port

I am attempting to receive data from the qu-bot at http://www.qu-bot.com. The robot has an ATML atmega16 microcontroller. I have written a program that runs on the robot which outputs data to its serial port. The program however stops whenever I connect to the controller. I tested this by adding a beep statement. The robot beeps as long as the program is running. The beeping stops when I connect to the robot. I tried qu-bo support and they suggested disabling the dtr flag on the serial port. I did that but no joy.

Is there anything else I can try?
[start of code running on the qu-bot]
Note:
This is written in some kind of proprietary variant of C which they call quick c.
// This code displays the uart functions.

```
int main(void)
{
    INIT();
    UART_INIT(57600);

    UART_PRINT("HELLO!!\n");
    DELAYS(1);
    UART_PRINT("MY NAME IS QU-BOT.\n");
    DELAYS(1);


    UART_PRINT("HELLO!!\n");
    UART_PRINT("YOU ARE USING UART SAMPLE CODES.\n");

    while(1)
    {
        UART_PRINT("test\n");

        BEEP();
        DELAYS(60);
    }
}
```

now for my python serial port reading program. I have tried this program both on raspbian and on windows 7 64bit. I am pasting the windows version. The raspbian version has a different name for the linux.

```
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial()
ser.port=8
ser.baudrate=57600
ser.setDsrDtr(False)


print 'initialized'
flag = ser.isOpen()
if flag:
 print 'port already open.'
 pass
else:
 ser.open() # opening the port 'ser' that was just created to receive data
 time.sleep(0.5)
print 'ready to read'
print ser
ser.write('a')
s=ser.read(4)
print s
ser.close()
Pranav
```

P.S. I have consulted the following links amongst others.

```
<https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/all>

<http://www.plainlystated.com/2013/06/raspberry-pi-serial-console/>

<http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection>

<https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/all>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience in serial communications with microcontrollers the most likely cause of this problem is that when you connect the serial cable to the robot it causes a phantom byte (due to electrical noise that happens when you make the connection) to look like it's coming from the controller - either this or the controller is sending a legitimate byte to the robot.  In either case it is likely that the arrival of a byte at the robot's serial port (even if it was only electrical noise mistaken to be a data byte - this is a *very* common occurrence) caused the robot's microcontroller to invoke the UART receive interrupt.  If you don't have an appropriate UART receive handler (ISR - Interrupt Service Routine) written and linked into the correct interrupt vector then your robot's microcontroller can go off into "deep space" upon the detection of the first incoming serial data byte - and make your robot appear to "hang".  If you intend to do "polled" serial communications (your code manually checks for received bytes in its main loop) instead of interrupt-driven (hardware detection of an incoming byte causes your UART Rx ISR to be invoked) then all you have to do is to disable UART interrupts and your problem should go away.